# mysqldump-cronjob creates a new php-file, each time it is called

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I have a cronjob that looks like this:

```
mysqldump -u XXX -pXXX XXX | gzip -9 > /data/web/xyz123/html/temporary/backup-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz
```

every time the cronjob is called, the .sql.gz-file is generated. All is good. But I recognized, that the cronjob also generates a file in the root Directory called crontab.php.1, crontab.php.2, crontab.php.3... every time the cronjob is called.

The relevant code in the crontab.php is:

```
  if(!empty($data['set_backup_email'])){
   if(sendmail($data['set_backup_email'], 'Backup '.date('Y-m-d'), 'Im Anhang befindet sich das Backup vom '.$day[date('N')].', '.date('d.m.Y').'.', $file, 'backup@abc123.xyz1')){
    protocol(61);
    unlink($file);
   }else{
    protocol(62);
    send2admin('Das Datenbank-Backup konnte nicht zugestellt werden');
   }
  }
```

Comment: how do you call the php cron job

Comment: i call it with wget https://urrrrrlllllll.com/crontab.php 2 minutes after the mysqldump

Comment: you are doing it wrong..

Comment: thats why i asked here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling php file in the wrong way.

run this command on your linux server

```
which php
```

it will give you the path to your php, it will be something like `/to/path/php`

Add the line in your cron tab as:

`* * * * *    /to/path/php   /filepath/crontab.php`

Use `*` as per your requirements.

The php file should be on the server.